# Database returning username check as incorrect

Tags: c#, .net, database, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2013

Whenever i check my database with correct data the database returns it as an incorrect username, im not sure whether it is my code, or my database, her is the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TOSHIBA0007\\TESTSERVER;Initial Catalog=users;Integrated Security=True");
            conn.Open();
            string checkuser = "select count(*) from userdatabase where Username=' " + Username.Text + " ' ";
            SqlCommand UserComm = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(UserComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ", ""));
            conn.Close();
            if (temp == 1)
            {
                conn.Open();
                string checkPasswordQuery = "select Password from userdatabase where Username=' "+Username.Text+" ' ";
                SqlCommand passCom = new SqlCommand(checkPasswordQuery, conn);
                string password = passCom.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ", "");
                if(password == Password.Text)
                {
                    Session["New"] = Username.Text;
                    Response.Write("Password Accepted");
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("Password Incorrect");
                }        
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Username is Incorrect");
            }
    }
}
```

any and all help will be greatly appreciated as i am stumped as to why this is not working.

Comment: Two things to note here:  1) Your code is *wide open* to SQL injection attacks, please use parameterized queries instead.  2) You're storing passwords in plain text.  ***Never store passwords in plain text.***  Hash the password immediately when it's received and store the hash.  When checking a password, hash it and compare the hashes.

Comment: if i change the value of temp it produces and error, actually that could be the issue

Comment: okay david, ill sort that out, im only beginning its local so its not to much of and issue right now but thank you for the advice

Comment: As David mentioned, there are a number of security problems that need to be addressed here.  In addition to that you are adding spaces to the password before you check it, which will most likely make it so no passwords ever match.

Comment: @user3306240: Well, consider the security issues in two separate categories.  SQL injection vulnerabilities are really your own problem, and you can sort that out in time.  But password storage is another matter.  As soon as you're accepting passwords from actual users, improperly handling those passwords is *grossly* irresponsible.  SQL injection exposes your system to attacks, but improper password handling exposes your *users* to attacks.  Think of the users first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem :** You are giving space before and after username in your query.

1.Replace This:

```
string checkuser = "select count(*) from userdatabase where Username=' " + Username.Text + " ' ";
```

With This:

```
 string checkuser = "select count(*) from userdatabase where Username='" + Username.Text + "'";
```

2.Replace This:

```
string checkPasswordQuery = "select Password from userdatabase where Username=' "+Username.Text+" ' ";
```

With This:

```
string checkPasswordQuery = "select Password from userdatabase where Username='"+Username.Text+"'";
```

**Suggestion: 1** your query is open to `sql injection attacks` so i would suggest you to use `parameterised queries` to avoid them.

**Suggestion 2 :** you don't need to do multiple comparisions for username and password.
you can write a single query as below to find the valid user:

```
select count(*) from userdatabase where Username=@username and Password=@password;
```

**Solution:** using `Parameterised Queries` with single query

```
protected void Button_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TOSHIBA0007\\TESTSERVER;Initial Catalog=users;Integrated Security=True");
        conn.Open();
        string checkuser = "select count(*) from userdatabase where Username=@username and Password=@password";
        SqlCommand UserComm = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
        UserComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username",Username.Text);
        UserComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password",Password.Text);
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(UserComm.ExecuteScalar());
        conn.Close();
        if (temp == 1)
        {
           Session["New"] = Username.Text;
           Response.Write("User Is Valid!");
        }
        else
        {
           Response.Write("Invalid User Credentials!");
        }   
}
```

**Suggestion 3:** you should not store passwords as plain text in Database, please take care of that. see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database) for more info on how to store passwords in a secured way.

Comment: And you should never let the user know if it was the username or the password that was incorrect. The response to the user should always be "Invalid" or "Valid" login... otherwise the user can use the system to find out which usernames exist in the system...